# Add location data to a csv file on S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture

Given 100,000 rows of longitude / latitude in a file like

```
longitude|latitude
-81.41071|45.63808
```

Would like to lookup the country, state, county using a geocode API

This isn't too hard, post to something like https://getthegeos/45.63808,-81.41071.json

And parse the returned .json to pull back the country etc..

What I'm wondering is a good way to architect this.

Simplest is of course just running it on an EC2 (maybe even on the AMI of the reverse geocoder instance)

Or use a glue job, or something with SQS queues.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty clear you'd want to use a shapefile for this. I'm a fan of using other StackExchange sites where they specialize in the topic (e.g. Machine Learning, Data Science or in this case GIS).

In this case, the Geographic Information Systems site has [a similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88011/from-coordinates-find-country-using-python) which itself references a [GitHub repo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88011/from-coordinates-find-country-using-python)

If, on the other hand, you're looking for more of end to end advice you probably would do better to ask it on the software engineering site.

Answer (score 0):

Was advised to use step functions and then invoke Glue Python Shell jobs.